# Stackdriver API to update a policy

Tags: google-cloud-stackdriver

I would like to update a stackdriver alert policy using the monitor api with gcloud.  I'm getting an error for the condition.  I'm basically trying to add a filter to get rid of /dev/loop.* devices. Any help would be very appreciated.

gcloud alpha monitoring policies update projects/projectnameID/alertPolicies/policynumberxxx/conditions/conditionnumberxxx \
--condition-filter='metric.type="agent.googleapis.com/disk/percent_used" AND resource.type="gce_instance"' metric.label."device"!=monitoring.regex.full_match "/dev/loop.*"

I can do this via the GUI but some legacy policies will only update via API calls.

Comment: Does this work? gcloud alpha monitoring policies update projects/projectnameID/alertPolicies/policynumberxxx/conditions/conditionnumberxxx \ --condition-filter='metric.type="agent.googleapis.com/disk/percent_used" AND resource.type="gce_instance" AND metric.label.device!=monitoring.regex.full_match("/dev/loop.*")'

Comment: Thanks for the reply: I get this ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.monitoring.policies.update) unrecognized arguments:  --condition-filter=metric.type="agent.googleapis.com/disk/percent_used" AND resource.type="gce_instance" AND metric.label.device!=monitoring.regex.full_match("/dev/loop.*")